# Position or layout of questions on a page to make questions appear side by side in Sharepoint survey

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, html, survey

How to change  the position or layout of questions on a page to make questions appear side by side in Sharepoint survey ?

Comment: You've asked this same question several times now. The lack of response should be an indicator about how easy it is to solve. It won't get any easier if you keep asking the same question.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an easy feat, hence there are very few answers on the web for that. The SharePoint Survey format is a dinosaur that goes way back to the days of WSS 3.

If you want flexibility, use a custom list instead of a survey and do what you want with the form in SharePoint Designer or with jQuery/Javascript.

For reporting export the data to Excel and create charts and dashboards.

That will probably be more time-efficient than trying to hack the built-in survey.